# angular/forms integer validator

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-validator

How can I validate my numeric input field to only accept integer and not any kind of decimal numbers (comma / dot)?

## Code

`Component`

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

this.savingData = this.formBuilder.group({
  amount: ['', Validators.required], // only accept integer 123000
});
```

`HTML`

[image: one]

```
<ion-input type="number" min="1" inputmode="numeric" formControlName="amount" placeholder="{{ 'SAVINGS.amount' | translate }}" ></ion-input>
```

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try Angular Reactive form [pattern validator](https://angular.io/api/forms/PatternValidator)

```
this.savingData = this.formBuilder.group({
  amount: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$")]], // only numbers
});
```

Comment: @mafortis add regex inside quotes updated answer checkout now

Comment: ok works this way `amount: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$")]],` thanks a lot

Comment: @mafortis  It will accept other chars as well but the form would be invalid though.

Comment: If you are OK with negative numbers too: `Validators.pattern('^-?[0-9]*$')`

Answer (score 2):

Try to use pattern like `\d+`. It is in `Validators.pattern()`

Comment: You mean I replace `Validators.required` with `Validators.pattern()`?

Comment: You can do this, or save required and use `\d*`